# Why do I need to cast NULL to column type?

Tags: postgresql, null, cast

I've got a helper that's generating some code to do bulk updates for me and generates SQL that looks like this:

(Both the active and core fields are of type `boolean`)

```
UPDATE fields as t set "active" = new_values."active","core" = new_values."core"
FROM (values 
(true,NULL,3419),
(false,NULL,3420)
) as new_values("active","core","id") WHERE new_values.id = t.id;
```

However it fails with:

> `ERROR:  column "core" is of type boolean but expression is of type text`

I can get it to work by adding `::boolean` to the nulls, but that just seems odd, why is NULL considered of type `TEXT`?

Also it's a bit tricky to cast because it would require quite a bit of a rework of the code for it to know what type it should cast NULLs to 
(the list of columns and values is currently being autogenerated from a simple array of JSON objects).

Why is this necessary and is there a more elegant solution that doesn't require the generating code to know the type of NULLs?

If it's relevant, I'm using [sequelize](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize) over Node.JS to do this, but am also getting the same result in the Postgres command line client.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is an interesting finding.  Normally, a NULL has no assumed data type, as you can see here:

```
SELECT pg_typeof(NULL);

 pg_typeof 
───────────
 unknown
```

This changes when a `VALUES` table comes into the picture:

```
SELECT pg_typeof(core) FROM (
    VALUES (NULL)
) new_values (core);

 pg_typeof 
───────────
 text
```

This behaviour is described in the source code at https://doxygen.postgresql.org/parse__coerce_8c.html#l01373:

```
 /*
  * If all the inputs were UNKNOWN type --- ie, unknown-type literals ---
  * then resolve as type TEXT.  This situation comes up with constructs
  * like SELECT (CASE WHEN foo THEN 'bar' ELSE 'baz' END); SELECT 'foo'
  * UNION SELECT 'bar'; It might seem desirable to leave the construct's
  * output type as UNKNOWN, but that really doesn't work, because we'd
  * probably end up needing a runtime coercion from UNKNOWN to something
  * else, and we usually won't have it.  We need to coerce the unknown
  * literals while they are still literals, so a decision has to be made
  * now.
  */
```

(Yes, PostgreSQL source code is relatively easy to understand and most places, thanks to excellent comments.)

The way out, however, might be the following.  Let's say you are always generating `VALUES` that match all columns of a given table (see the second note below for other cases).  From your example, a small trick could possibly help:

```
SELECT (x).* FROM (VALUES ((TRUE, NULL, 1234)::fields)) t(x);

 active │ core │  id  
────────┼──────┼──────
 t      │      │ 1234
```

Here you use [row expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/rowtypes.html#ROWTYPES-USAGE) casted to the table's type, and then extracting them back to a table.

Based on the above, your `UPDATE` could look like

```
UPDATE fields AS t set active = (x).active, core = (x).core
FROM ( VALUES
           ((true, NULL, 3419)::fields),
           ((false, NULL, 3420)::fields)
     ) AS new_values(x) WHERE (x).id = t.id;
```

### Notes:

- I removed the double quotes for better human readability, but you can keep them as they help when generating (column) names.
- if you need only a subset of the columns, you can [create custom types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtype.html) for this purpose.  Use them the same way as you would above (where I use the type automatically created with the table, holding the row structure of the latter).

Look at the whole thing working on [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=9a51eb9d612a4eb2e22ae58b55f596eb).

Comment: Thanks, this is interesting, however, for me, the code above produces `Cannot cast type boolean to bigint in column 1` (the error points at the :: between the first fields statement)

Comment: @ChristopherJ the answer assumes that the table called `fields` has 3 columns, `(active, core, id)` with boolean, boolean and int/bigint types. Does your table have more columns or different types or are the columns defined in different order?

Comment: Ah i see, thanks, yep there are more columns and in different order. Got it thank you