# Why does PostgreSQL explicitly cast NULL to parameter data type in functions?

Tags: postgresql, null

Let's say I create the following function:

```
create or replace function my_new_function(
    p_something text default null
)
etc....
```

But if I go to check the function on PostgreSQL I see this instead:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_new_function(p_something text default NULL::text)
```

Why does it do that?

Answer (score 2):

In short: you stumbled across an internal detail, of how postgres handles datatypes in default values. You likely just want to keep it.

As described in
[Why do I need to cast NULL to column type?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/228046/why-do-i-need-to-cast-null-to-column-type?rq=1), the default type of NULL is *unknown* in most cases, so the type info is appended when you set a default. (The same can happen to column defaults also)

When postgres displays the function, it likely does not remember how you created it, so it displays `null::text`. For column defaults, postgres sometimes recognizes that the user would find the typecast irrelevant and removes it, but sometimes it does not (not sure when exactly). So if you state `default null` that can be seen as default `NULL::varchar(30)` for instance.
For tables, this can be "fixed" with `... drop default`, but I think this would make the function parameter required.